# Generate random values using an empirical cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, distributions, python, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

I have a set of data points that I have used to generate my empirical CDF which looks like this (to simplify things I have reduced the number of points for this question but it shouldn't matter):
[image: ECDF Plot]

Given this data and plot I need to somehow generate random values which follow this distribution. I admit that I am quite rusty when it comes to probability, but as far as I understand I need to first generate the PDF and then from there I can do what I want. Is that accurate? Or what is the best way to get what I want?

If interested in giving an example for the answer, here are the X and Y array for the data points of the ECDF plot. I am using Python but I guess a language agnostic answer would also be really helpful

```
x = [107.6697676209896, 430.70331251794784, 1975.0646306785532, 7793.524079329409, 27569.66699567533, 62566.73646946178, 222847.1449910263, 832591.8949493016, 2827054.7454871265, 10000733.572934577]
```

```
y = [0.001603113424267999, 0.04812202549318534, 0.09825964339269633, 0.14190143419466905, 0.27204351414405636, 0.46590411495145756, 0.6008552899988212, 0.6796719668120879, 0.8400864397710662, 0.9427752938262692]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You generate such a random variable by sampling randomly from the data.

Answer (score 6):

To generate a random variable from an empirical distribution, you just sample at random from the data used to create that distribution.  So, if you have sample values $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,...,x_n)$ you can generate independent random values $\tilde{X}_1,...,\tilde{X}_m$ from the empirical distribution for this sample by taking:

$$\tilde{X}_i \equiv x_{I_i}
\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad
I_1,...,I_m \sim \text{IID U} \{ 1,...,n \}.$$

It is simple to show that $\tilde{X}_1,...,\tilde{X}_m \sim \text{IID }F_\mathbf{x}$ (i.e., the values are independent draws from the empirical distribution for $\mathbf{x}$).

Answer (score 2):

Given samples $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_N$, a empirical distribution $d$ is defined as $d(x)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\delta_{X_i}(x)$. This is just a categorical distribution you can easily sample from. However, I believe what you are seeking is a smoothed version of the empirical distribution. Then, you should use kernel density estimation, $\hat d(x)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^NK_h(x-X_i)$, where $K$ is the kernel function. Some valid kernel functions are shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)#Kernel_functions_in_common_use).

The following code fits the data with the scikit-learn package. Since the data scale is across multiple magnitudes, it is better to fit it on the log domain. Once you get a fitted density function $kde$, you can sample from it by calling its method `sample(n_samples)`.

```py
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
X = np.array([107.6697676209896, 430.70331251794784, 1975.0646306785532, 7793.524079329409, 27569.66699567533, 62566.73646946178, 222847.1449910263, 832591.8949493016, 2827054.7454871265, 10000733.572934577]
).reshape(-1,1)

# Bandwidth controls the smoothness of the density. The larger, the smoother.
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='exponential', bandwidth=3e6).fit(X)
x = np.linspace(0, 1e7, 1000).reshape(-1,1)
y = np.exp(kde.score_samples(x))
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(x, y)

log_X = np.log(X) # Transform the data into log domain
log_kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=2.0).fit(log_X)
log_x = np.linspace(3, 17, 1000).reshape(-1,1)
log_y = np.exp(log_kde.score_samples(log_x))
plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(log_x, log_y)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thanks! I see that you are not using my Y values, how does that make sense? My X values are not actual values. I obtained the X and Y values simply by extracting them from a plot in a paper. They are just equally distant points (pixel wise) which were extracted using a software.

Comment: @Tommy95 An empirical CDF is a step function. Therefore, the CDF you obtained is actually a linearly interpolated CDF.  Its Y-value is not necessary for density estimation. All you need is just the set of data points.  However, you can also use the interpolated CDF to generate a density function, for which the density is just the slope in the CDF.

Comment: but then how would it be able to work without having an idea of the Y values? Let's say the second x point has an actual y value of 0.98 and then all the other points are slowly increasing towards 1. Then if I just use the x values (let's assume I have 10 of them), how would it know that 98% of the values are lower than the second x value?

Comment: @Tommy95 By data points, I mean the raw dataset you have. It's meaningless to use some equally distant points. In the raw dataset, roughly 98% of data points are below the 0.98-quantile.